# Statistics about webservers and browsers SSLv3.0 support

Tags: tls, statistics

Since I'm working on a little historical document about the SSLv3.0 protocol and it's most important attacks, it would be lovely to add some statistics about how many webservers and browsers still support SSLv3.0 nowadays, even after the POODLE bite event.

Sadly I've not been able to find such updated statistics. So, are there any statistics after the POODLE attack about this? If not, what would be the most recent ones?

I'm seeking after something similar to  [Ivan Ristic's survey](http://blog.ivanristic.com/Qualys_SSL_Labs-State_of_SSL_2010-v1.6.pdf) on page 37, but newer.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSLPulse, a monthly scan of SSL amongst the 200,000 biggest websites, has statistics on SSL 3.0 support: https://www.trustworthyinternet.org/ssl-pulse/

They publish at the beginning of each month, so any day now there should be new data. Already you can see SSL 3.0 support dropped from 98% to 60% from October to November.

(You can use the "Previous" and "Next" buttons at the top right to view the data for each month.)

Coincidentally, Ivan Ristic is also involved in this project.

EDIT: Also see:

https://zmap.io/sslv3/